# LyX and biblatex authoryear-comp and same authors: Parentheses wrong

Tags: biblatex, lyx

I use LyX with biblatex 2.9a, biber 1.9 and the authoryear-comp style. My biblatex configuration is below:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-comp,natbib=true]{biblatex}
```

When I insert two citations from the same authors and years (this is `\citet{author2014a,author2014b}` in the source code panel), I want LyX / LaTeX to produce

> Author (2014a, b)

At least, this is what I guess should be returned from the `authoryear-comp` style. Instead, I get

> Author (2014a), b

I get the same result when I insert the following LaTeX code as `ERT`: `\textcite{author2014a,author2014b}`.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: Which biblatex and biber version?

Comment: `biber --version` in a command line/terminal, or look in the first line of the `.blg` file to find the version number.

Comment: I don't think lyx supports biber. Try backend=bibtex

Comment: That is very odd indeed, can you come up with an MWE? Do you have any other code that could modify the output of citation commands?

Comment: When I was trying to build a MWE I figured out where the problem came from. Earlier, I added some code in order to define the authors' names as hyperlinks as well (copied from somewhere). Outcommenting these lines leads to the desired citation result and I can live without hyperlinked names.

Comment: @MatthiasGomolka Would you like to add an answer, or should we close this question?

Comment: Closing the question would be best.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a problem that is not in the question (additional code modifying the behaviour of cite commands) and has since been resolved by the OP themselves (see comments above).

Answer (score 0):

From the lyx wiki

To change from bibtex to biber, go toLyX→Preferences→Settings→Output→LaTeX and change the bibtex commandfrom bibtex to biber (you can also input biber options, if you need them). Also note that you should pass the option backend=biber (instead ofbackend=bibtex) to the \usepackage[...]{biblatex} call if you use biber, although this is not strictly necessary anymore in recent biblatex releases which default to biber if you do not pass the backend option at all.

Comment: I am not sure how this answers the OPs question. Apparently, he is already (and successfully) using LyX with `biblatex` and `biber`, but has an issue regarding the resulting citation style.

Comment: This is true. Apart from the rather small problem that I desdribed above, biblatex, biber and LyX work fine. I followed the instructions from the [LyX Wiki](http://wiki.lyx.org/BibTeX/Biblatex#using-biber).